# How to import and scrape a html file into a collection in APEX

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

Problem: I have an invoice that is not is not structured conveniently. It's in a form of a HTML webpage containing of few tables - two columns - key and pair values.
I want to enable user to select that file, import it into APEX page, **scrape** that file into collection and work on it e.g. checking if values match with ones that are currently in my database.
Next, if validation is successful, user may change some data on collection. After that that file is saved into a database table.

I've tried to look up some plugins to do so but nothing was close unfortunately. I'm new to that technology. Could you give me some ideas on how to do that the proper way. **Scraping** itself will be a problem so I need some kind of language to manipulate html code.

Comment: Probably best you have a look at [Oracle's XML querying capabilities](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/xdb04cre.htm#GUID-0FDD8ABE-F94B-42CB-B135-93BC67225737)

Comment: @TonyAndrews I don't see how it helps mi with scrapping my HTML file. It contains of several tables, not one. I am thinking of JavaScript function to do so.

Comment: Sorry you're quite right!

Comment: BTW I think you probably mean "scrape" rather than "scrap"!

Comment: Wouldn't XML be in the ballpark? Processing hierarchical, tagged data?
I could think of the required mechanics for JavaScript, but it seems laborious if the db could do it.